# extract agents stored as a parameter inside one agent in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

[extract agents from a parameter]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXoOk.jpg
I have an agent (shipment) with amount parameter. I want to make decisions according to every single shipment to decide where to go. the problem i've struggled with is how to transform my  one agent per arrival to many agents equals to the parameter (amount) after he gets out of the queue, queue1 .I used unbatch block to illustrate what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

you can't unbatch things if you haven't batched them before..instead to achieve the same thing you can use a split block

With the split block you can define the number of copies based on that amount parameter and you can define the type of agent copied as well

Comment: I had tried that and worked fine.